# Angular and NPM issue

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, electron, angular9

I'm currently learning angular 9 so when i tried to install node js and npm with latest version that is `node version 12.*` and `npm version 6.14.*`. I'm facing problem whith `ng new` and `npm install command`
Issues are as follows:

```
sudo npm install 
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ure":"-----BEGIN PGP '

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/frustrated_coder/.npm/_logs/2020-03-29T14_31_40_275Z-debug.log
```

ng new angular-test

```
Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...200772","tarball":"ht'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/frustrated_coder/.npm/_logs/2020-03-29T14_20_56_952Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Also i working on angular-electron but the majority of the problem is with that as well due to npm install command in it.
This is the `https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron` url from where i'm cloning angular electron.

Comment: so you have cloned angular-electron and there you are installing npm install, right ?

Comment: what is the version of Angular in your machine ?

Comment: "so you have cloned angular-electron and there you are installing npm install, right" yes to include node_modules and dev dependencies

Comment: let m try on my local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Windows Powershell as an administrator and run;

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```